# NPM can't install some packages

Tags: node.js, npm

I have recently done a clean reformatting of my Windows PC, installed Atom, and Node.js and started by installing the package `dualshock`. I give it a minute and it fails with this error code:

```
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:194:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:210:5)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:270:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.18363
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Starb\node_modules\node-hid
gyp ERR! node -v v13.2.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.0.5
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN starb@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN starb@1.0.0 No repository field.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! node-hid@0.5.7 install: `prebuild-install || node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the node-hid@0.5.7 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Starb\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-11-29T13_46_21_869Z-debug.log
```

I tried reinstalling gyp, Node, cleaning the cache, anything you can possibly imagine. i googled everywhere and couldnt find any solution that worked.

[Full log from the console](https://textuploader.com/1ogr9)

Answer (score 0):

If you use windows you are probably missing windows-build-tools

```
npm install --global --production windows-build-tools
```

Reference: https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp

Comment: I have already tried it. It gave me the same error even after i installed windows-build-tools on Powershell with admin privileges.